# How do I map and read my dynamic form entries in Struts 1?

Tags: javascript, java, struts

I'm following along with [this](https://codesilo.wordpress.com/2010/09/14/dynamic-forms-with-map-backed-actionforms-in-struts-1/) post to create dynamic forms in Struts 1.  So far, I have set up my hashmaps in my ActionForm to read this data on entry:

```
    public int getCount2() {
        return count2;
    }

    public void setCount2(int count) {
        this.count2 = count2;
    }

    public Map getChildObjects(){
        return childObjects;
    }

    public void setChild(String key, Object child){
        childObjects.put(key, child);
    }

    public Object getChild(String key){
        return childObjects.get(key);
    }
```

And I have set this map's keys and values in the JSP function.

```
    var elementCount = parseInt(document.getElementById("count2").value);

    var textFirstName = document.createElement("input");
        ...
        textFirstName.setAttribute("name","childObjects(FirstName"+ elementCount +")");
        ...
```

I have the hidden field "Count2" declared in the HTML, and I have no JSP errors coming up when I load the page or any issues adding these document elements, but when I try to read the form data, even when I fill in these vaules, the mapping comes back empty.

How do I read this data into my maps, and then read them back when submitting my Action?

Answer (score 0):

I went through the example , but couldn't understand how different named DOM elements can be assigned to a HashMap with single name , i,e if there are :

```
<input type="text" name="name1" />
<input type="text" name="name2" />
```

then action file expects 2 variables by name name1 and name2 , but if you can create DOM elements with same name i,e :

```
<input type="text" name="testVal" />
<input type="text" name="testVal" />
```

then in action file you can create a `string[] testVal` array variable and you will have all input values populated in it .

correct me if I'm wrong with HashMap way .

**Edit :**

True, you won't able to identify each elements, and by the way it's getting named in the posted code i don't think it's possible  :

```
childObjects(FirstName"+ elementCount +");
```

try doing this :

```
childObjects[elementCount];
```

replace `() with []` , and remove `firstName` prefix along with index.

that should assign it to a HashMap by name `childObjects`.

This works in Struts 2. Assuming it should work in struts 1 aswell.

Comment: If you do it that way, how are you supposed to identify each input value if you're using a keyed hashmap?